# google API exchange short lived access token for refresh token

Tags: google-api

In the [docs](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2) it says:

> Access tokens have limited lifetimes. If your application needs access to a Google API beyond the lifetime of a single access token, it can obtain a refresh token. A refresh token allows your application to obtain new access tokens.

However I don't see anywhere in the documentation how to exchange the short lived token achieved here in the browser:

```
window.google.accounts.oauth2.initTokenClient
```

For a long lived refresh token?

Answer (score 1):

### Exchange flow

Here is how I use cURL to get the authorization code:

> curl 
> --request POST 
> --data "code=[Authorization code from authorization link]&
> client_id=[Application Client Id]&
> client_secret=[Application Client Secret]&
> redirect_uri=[link]&
> grant_type=authorization_code" 
> https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token

Then exchange it for a refresh token.

> curl 
> --request POST 
> --data 'client_id=[Application Client Id]&client_secret=[Application Client Secret]&refresh_token=[Refresh token granted by previous
> step]&grant_type=refresh_token' 
> https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token

### Refresh tokens

According to Google documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/token-types#refresh), by default, access tokens and ID tokens are valid for 1 hour. A refresh token is a special token that is used to obtain additional access tokens or ID tokens. When your application first authenticates, it receives an access token or ID token, as well as a refresh token. Later, if the application needs to access resources again, and the previously provided token has expired, it uses the refresh token to request a new token. Refresh tokens are used only for user authentication, such as for Cloud Identity or Google Workspace.

Refresh tokens don't have a set lifetime; they can expire, but otherwise they continue to be usable. For user access in Google Workspace or Cloud Identity premium edition, you can configure the session length to ensure that a user must log in periodically to retain access to Google Cloud services.

If your application is creating and managing its own tokens, it also needs to manage refresh tokens.

### They can expire

A refresh token might stop working for one of these reasons:

- The user has revoked your app's access.
- The refresh token has not been used for six months.
- The user changed passwords and the refresh token contains Gmail scopes
- The user account has exceeded a maximum number of granted (live)
  refresh tokens.
- The user belongs to a Google Cloud Platform organization that has
  session control policies in effect.